# How can I accept this cookies using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to scrape this website https://www.parkers.co.uk but for some reason I cannot seem to get past the cookies pop up, I've tried with this code

cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]/div[5]/button[2]')
cookies.click()

but it doesn't seem to be working, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='SP Consent Message']")
 driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Accept All']").click()
```